# Covariance issue with interfaces causes back and forth casting

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, covariance

I'm stuck using .NET 3.5 for a project I'm working on. I'm running into a minor, yet annoying, covariance issue. This is a similar pattern to what I have currently:

```
public interface ISupportSomething<T> where T : struct
{
    T StructProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SupportSomething : ISupportSomething<int>
{
    public int StructProperty { get; set; }
}

public static class ISupportSomethingExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ISupportSomething<T>> Method<T>
            (this IEnumerable<ISupportSomething<T>> collection)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class SupportTester
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        IEnumerable<SupportSomething> source;

        // invalid, i would generally fix this with a covariant
        // declaration: ISupportSomething<out T>
        var methodResult1 = source.Method();

        // valid
        var methodResult2 = source.Cast<ISupportSomething<int>>().Method();

        // this means that if i want to make a function that
        // returns an IEnumerable<SupportSomething> that
        // has called ISupportSomethingExtensions.Method i
        // have to do this cast back and forth approach

    }

    // here is a similar function to what i have that showcases the ugliness
    // of calling this extension method
    private IEnumerable<SupportSomething> SomeFunction()
    {
        IEnumerable<SupportSomething> source;

        var tempSourceList = source.Cast<ISupportSomething<int>>();

        tempSourceList = tempSourceList.Method();

        return tempSourceList; // invalid
        return tempSourceList.Cast<SupportSomething>(); //valid
    }
}
```

My question is fairly simple and I think I already know the answer but: is there a way, with .NET 3.5, to not have to do this back and forth casting when dealing with these objects (see last function)?

I'm guessing that I'm out of luck and have to do it that way because there is no generic support for covariance until .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the extension method like so:

```
public static class ISupportSomethingExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T1> Method<T1, T2>
            (this IEnumerable<T1> collection)
        where T1 : ISupportSomething<T2>
        where T2 : struct
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't need to rely on `IEnumerable` being covariant to work.

The unfortunate site effect of this alteration is that `Method` will no longer be able to have it's generic arguments inferred, you need to list the explicitly:

```
private IEnumerable<SupportSomething> SomeFunction()
{
    IEnumerable<SupportSomething> source = Enumerable.Empty<SupportSomething>();

    return source.Method<SupportSomething, int>();
}
```